# Is there a good 3d software renderer for Java?

Tags: opengl, rendering, java-3d

I have a PC with a good CPU but slow GPU (integrated graphics card). I have noticed that some commercial games work much better using their software renderers instead of OpenGL or DirectX. I am making a Java app that will use JOGL/LWJGL to access OpenGL. To enable a software rendering option, should I look at a pure-Java software renderer, or native software-only OpenGL implementations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install [Mesa 3D](http://www.mesa3d.org/). This OSS project supplies an OpenGL driver for Windows which is based on a software renderer.